# nodejs async/await try/catch jest test passing when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs, ecmascript-2017

I am learning jest testing using latest ecmascript syntax for my MongoDB back-end code. I am testing right now to see if the test will fail the test if I try to find a document from an empty collection.

The cursor should be `null` as a result since nothing returns, and that means the cursor is falsey, but the test below still passes even when I tell it to expect truthy and I don't know why:

```
import config from './config'
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

it('sample test', () => {
  mongodb.MongoClient.connect(config.mongodb.url, async (connectErr, db) => {
    expect(db).toBeTruthy()
    let cursor
    try {
      cursor = await db.collection('my_collection').findOne()
      // cursor is null, but test still passes below
      expect(cursor).toBeTruthy()
    } catch (findErr) {
      db.close()
    }
  })
})
```

Also, is this a good test test style? I read somewhere that you shouldn't use try/catch blocks in testing. But that is what you would use to handle async/await errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `async` functions as callbacks - as callbacks are not supposed to return promises; their results will be ignored (and the rejection won't be handled). You should pass the `async` function to `it` itself, assuming that Jest knows how to deal with promises.

```
it('sample test', async () => {
  const db = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(config.mongodb.url);
  expect(db).toBeTruthy();
  try {
    const cursor = await db.collection('my_collection').findOne();
    expect(cursor).toBeTruthy();
  } finally { // don't `catch` exceptions you want to bubble
    db.close()
  }
});
```